# IE7 only scrolls to anchor in a new window

Tags: javascript, anchor, internet-explorer-7

I have a page (**pageA**) that contains tabbed panes, the content of each pane is represented by a DIV element and it has a unique ID e.g id="tab1"

```
<div id="tab1">Contents of tab</div>
```

I have another page (**pageB**) that has an A element that links to a specific tab

```
<a href="otherpage.html#tab2">Tab 2</a>
```

On IE7 **pageA** with the tabs on will only scroll if I open the link in a new window from **pageB**

Has anyone come across this issue and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the url that is being constructed by the anchor in IE7 is not valid:

```
<a href='#skipNav'>Skip</a> -> <url>/#/skipNav
```

so the easiest solution is to place a full url with # in the anchor. This will prevent IE7 to construct it from scratch (url should be server side generated in order to avoid Dev/Test/Qa/Prd transformation problems):

```
<a href='<url>/#skipNav'>Sip</a>
```

<del>EDIT:
if the error still occurs try adding a random query string. It's a dirty solution but what is not dirty in IE7</del>

EDIT:
here's a great example of another approach: [window.location = #anchor doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173394/window-location-anchor-doesnt-work-in-ie)
In a nutshell:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0); return false;'">Back to top</a>
```